# How to change frequency of AKMorphingOscillatorBank countinuously in Audiokit?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am new to Audiokit. I want to build a tuneable monophonic wavetable-oscillator with morphable table output that could be synced to an others oscillators frequency.

I startet with AKMorphingOscillatorBank but could not find out how to change its frequency countinuously, not stepweise.

At the moment I start a note with

```
vco1.play(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber(Int(noteNumber) + offset1), velocity: velocity, frequency: vco1Freq)
```

but changing the frequency while a note is played is not possible that way.

I want to have sequence of notes playing a base frequency tone and a knob that changes the base frequency of the oscillator continuously when rotated - like triggering an eurorack VCO module und turning the frequency knob...
thnx!

Comment: Could you paste more code of what you already tried? Especially how did you try to change the frequency? Called vco1.play again oder change vco1Freq?

Comment: I added a track to a sequencer. the sequencer calls the play method of my AKPolyphonicNode. there I use the play method of the AKMorphingOscillatorBank.
I then added a knob that changes the vco1Freq variable that is used in the play method.

Comment: I think I asked too many questions in one here so I voted to close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want something monophonic, then you could use AKMorphingOscillator instead of AKMorphingOscillatorBank.  It will allow you to control the frequency continuously.

Comment: How could I oversee that!? :-)

Comment: Does this mean I need to put my audio source nodes inside an AKOperationGenerator instead of an AKPolyphonicNode?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? I'm not at all familiar with Eurorack (or much else from the analog world). I understand you want the knob to control the osc frequency, but what does the sequencer control?

Comment: The sequencer should add frequency shifts.

Comment: Sorry, not really sure what you mean by 'frequency shifts'. But you can control the triggering and freq of the osc via a callback function from an AKCallbackInstrument connected to the sequencer.  For triggering you could use the .start() and .stop() methods of an AKAmplitudeEnvelope connected to the osc.  I'm not sure what you need the AKOperationGenerator for (although I might be misunderstanding).

Comment: I'm sorry if I do not express myself understandably. I think I know now which direction I have to go.
I think I asked too many questions in one so I will vote to close this one. thank you very much though!